Proof of $\int x^{2m}\Bigg|\frac{f(x+\frac{a}{2})-f(x-\frac{a}{2})}{a}\Bigg|^2\,dx\lesssim\int x^{2m}|f'(x)|^2\,dx$.
I am trying to prove that if $f$ is an even function then the inequality $$\sup_{a\in\mathbb R}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2m}\Bigg|\frac{f(x+\frac{a}{2})-f(x-\frac{a}{2})}{a}\Bigg|^2\,dx\lesssim\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2m}|f'(x)|^2\,dx$$ holds for any integer $m\geq0$.
Attempt of proof. Please let me know if it holds.
We have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2m}\Bigg|\frac{f(x+\frac{a}{2})-f(x-\frac{a}{2})}{a}\Bigg|^2\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2m}}{a^2}\Bigg|\int_{u=-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\partial_u(f(x+ua))\,du\Bigg|^2\,dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2m}}{a^2}\Bigg|\int_{u=-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}af'(x+ua)\,du\Bigg|^2\,dx.$$ Now, using Minkowski's integral inequality,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2m}\Bigg|\frac{f(x+\frac{a}{2})-f(x-\frac{a}{2})}{a}\Bigg|^2\,dx\lesssim \Bigg(\int_{u=-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\int_\infty^\infty x^{2m}|f'(x+ua)|^2\,dx\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\,du\Bigg)^2$$
$$\lesssim\sup_{|u|\leq\frac{1}{2}}\int_\infty^\infty x^{2m}|f'(x+ua)|^2\,dx=\sup_{|u|\leq\frac{1}{2}}\int_\infty^\infty (x-ua)^{2m}|f'(x)|^2\,dx.$$
Observe that if $m=0$ then we are done. Consider now $m\geq 1$. Since $f$ is even, $|f(x)|$ is even and thus the maximum of the function $$I(u)=\int_\infty^\infty (x-ua)^{2m}|f'(x)|^2\,dx$$ is attained at $u=0$. (Too see this, we differentiate: $$I(u)=-\int_\infty^\infty 2ma(x-ua)^{2m-1}|f'(x)|^2\,dx$$ which implies a maximum point at $u=0$.)

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Would you clarify what ‘$\lesssim$’ signifies here?

You should add the (implicit) hypothesis that $f$ is differentiable (almost) everywhere.

@Aruralreader $a \lesssim b$ is a quite standard notation for $a\leq Cb$ with $C>0$

Thanks @PabloHerrera, it’s appreciated. I’ve been in the business decades and never seen that interpretation. +1. So in the question, $C$ doesn’t depend on $a$ or $m$ or $f$?

@Aruralreader I don't know the origins of that notation, but in the numerics, analysis, and PDE community, it is common to see it in several papers to avoid writing too many constants. The number $C>0$ must be independent of $a$ and $b$, but it can be dependent on any other parameters.

Why don't you try expanding those functions as Taylor series?:
$$f\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)=f(x)+f'(x)\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\mathcal O\left(\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^3\right)$$
$$f\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)=f(x)-f'(x)\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\mathcal O\left(\left(-\frac{a}{2}\right)^3\right)$$
Then,
$$f\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)-f\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}}{n!}(x)[1-(-1)^n]\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(2n+1)}(x)}{(2n+1)!}\frac{a^{2n+1}}{2^{2n}},$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac{f\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)-f\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)}{a}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(2n+1)}(x)}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2n}$$
In addition, by the triangle inequality we know that
$$\left|\frac{f\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)-f\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)}{a}\right|\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|f^{(2n+1)}(x)|}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2n}$$
holds since $f$, being even, implies $f^{(2n+1)}$ are odd, and thus, they can be negative. It then follows
$$\left|\frac{f\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)-f\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)}{a}\right|^2\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{|f^{(2n+1)}(x)f^{(2m+1)}(x)|}{(2n+1)!(2m+1)!}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2(n+m)}$$
Next, we multiply by $x^{2m}$ and integrate with respect to $x$ for $x\in\mathbf R$ on both sides:
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2m}\left|\frac{f\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)-f\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)}{a}\right|^2\,\mathrm dx\\
&\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)!(2m+1)!}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2(n+m)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2m}|f^{(2n+1)}(x)f^{(2m+1)}(x)|\,\mathrm dx,
\end{align}
and, finally, if we only pick the first order term it yields
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2m}\left|\frac{f\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)-f\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)}{a}\right|^2\,\mathrm dx \lesssim\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2m}|f'(x)|^2\,\mathrm dx$$

Why are we allowed to "pick" the first order term?
